# Java Regular Expressions find matches within x characters

Tags: java, regex

I've been pulling my hair out over this, and I know it's a simple solution that just seems to escape me at the moment.

I am attempting to perform a match using a Regex code (client side, character classes only) that will match "looking for" within 20 spaces (any character) of "male".
I don't care what the characters or spaces are, it must not find a match if the two words/phrases are more than 20 characters apart.

I have the code setup to match the phrases I just need to know how to set the parameter of a distance search. "Only match Looking for with Male if they are within zero to twenty characters of each other.

Comment: Can `male` be multiple times in the string?

Comment: Is "looking for female" also valid?

Comment: "client side, character classes only" != "java regular expressions" - you need to be more specific about what is actually valid to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?i).*looking for.{0,20}male.*
```

The (?i) flag is just "ignore case".

**EDIT**:
with the suggestions:

```
Pattern.compile("(?is).*\\blooking for\\b.{0,20}\\bman\\b.*");
```

Comment: Thank you, I attempted the exact code before and it didn't seem to work. Curious why did you use .* around the code prior to the edit?

Comment: Also needs `s` flag to allow dot to match newline (assuming "looking for:<newline>male" is valid). And probably makes sense to make it non-greedy too, since male is more likely to be nearer than further away. so  `(?is)looking for.{0,20}?male`

Comment: Oh, and probably want appropriately placed `\b` too, unless "Looking forlorn, a female gerbil crawls along." should be matched.

Comment: @confused the .* was because I did something a lot more complicated with look-ahead, which I realized was unneeded, but I forgot to drop the .* at first.

Comment: @confused I tried it on some simple example and it seems to work.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to further this to include it NOT to match if any of this is followed by "not required". Would you recommend using forward look ahead? I'm trying (?!.{0,20}not required) but that doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: @confused OK, so it seems the .* are needed at both ends of the expression. It doesn't seem to work otherwise if there's something before or after "looking for... man". I'm a bit puzzled. I re-edited my answer to add ".*" at both ends. I'd like to have an explanation from someone though. As for the look ahead: `(?is).*\\blooking for\\b.{0,20}\\bman\\b(?!.*not required).*` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't pull your hair out but instead start with the root of the issue? I mean can't you write your code/application more logical so you wouldn't need to do such weird string search with even weirder distance matching?

Comment: Not the way the system is setup. I can only use character classes, so if you have a better way I'm all ears.

Comment: confused: You cannot match distance only using "character classes"; a character class allows you to select which single character matches, not how many match (that's what quantifiers are for). Fix the question to state explicitly what you can use, and if you cannot use either the Java language or the java.util.regex library then remove the "java" tag because it's misleading/invalid.